Omit function parameters on condition in Kotlin
If I have a function or constructor in Kotlin, how do I omit certain parameters with a conditional?  For example:
val capture = ScaleCapture(
    if (jsonObject.has(JSON.ID))
        id = jsonObject.getInt(JSON.ID),
    if (jsonObject.has(JSON.WEIGHT))
        weight = jsonObject.getInt(JSON.WEIGHT)
)

//...

data class ScaleCapture(
    val id: Int = 0
)

What I want is to ensure that, rather than sending a null value for a given parameter, the parameter is omitted entirely at the call site, which allows the default value to be used.  If a function has multiple parameters with default values, it would be cumbersome to write out every possible combination of available parameters:
// Example with 2 parameters with default values
// We cannot pass null values because this is not the same as an omission due to default parameter values

if (jsonObject.has(JSON.ID)) {
    if (jsonObject.has(JSON.WEIGHT)) {
        return ScaleCapture(
            id = jsonObject.getInt(JSON.ID),
            weight = jsonObject.getInt(JSON.WEIGHT))
    } else {
        return ScaleCapture(
            id = jsonObject.getInt(JSON.ID)
    } else if(jsonObject.has(JSON.WEIGHT)) {
        return ScaleCapture(
            weight = jsonObject.getInt(JSON.WEIGHT))
    } else {
        return ScaleCapture()
}

//...

data class ScaleCapture(
    val id: Int = 0,
    val data: Int = 0
)

How do I accomplish this?  I checked the Kotlin documentation under default values, but there wasn't much information.

Just for the sake of argument, there are two other options.
Mutable state
Just go for mutable state:
data class ScaleCapture(
    var id: Int = 0,
    var data: String = "",
)

val scaleCapture = ScaleCapture()
if (jsonObject.has(JSON.ID)) scaleCapture.id = jsonObject.getInt(JSON.ID)
if (jsonObject.has(JSON.WEIGHT)) scaleCapture.data = jsonObject.getString(JSON.WEIGHT)

Reflection
If you want the ScaleCapture to be immutable, you could also opt by going the full-fledged reflection way:
data class ScaleCapture(
    val id: Int = 0,
    val data: String = "",
)

val parameters = mutableMapOf<KParameter, Any>()
if (jsonObject.has(JSON.ID)) parameters.put(primaryConstructor.parameters.first { it.name == "id" }, jsonObject.getInt(JSON.ID))
if (jsonObject.has(JSON.WEIGHT)) parameters.put(primaryConstructor.parameters.first { it.name == "data" }, jsonObject.getString(JSON.WEIGHT))

val primaryConstructor = ScaleCapture::class.primaryConstructor!!
val scaleCapture = primaryConstructor.callBy(parameters)

My opinion
I like immutability a lot, but using reflection is super dirty. Personally I would create two types. The first mutable and the next immutable:
private data class MutableScaleCapture(
    var id: Int = 0,
    var data: String = "",
)

data class ScaleCapture(
    val id: Int,
    val data: String,
)

Then you can just map the mutable one to an immutable and expose that one to the rest of your application:
val capture = MutableScaleCapture()
// if (jsonObject.has(JSON.ID)) scaleCapture.id = <something>
// .. etc

ScaleCapture(capture.id, capture.data)


Good thinking, but instead of having a mutable type (for object construction) and an immutable type (for general usage) you could enforce that pattern by only allowing object contstruction via a Builder.

You can’t do exactly what you’re asking to do because default values in calls are evaluated at compile time (see Leviathan’s answer).
So I would add a pseudo-constructor to your data class that takes null values and produces the call you need. This lets you keep the conditional code at the source and you can significantly simplify it by moving where you define the default values.
data class ScaleCapture(val id: Int, val data: Int) {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(id: Int? = null, data: Int? = null) =
            ScaleCapture(id ?: 0, data ?: 0)
    }
}


@JacobvanLingen, thank you for the corrections. I don’t like the linked article though because it also advocates confusing (ill-advised) uses of invoke operators.

You cannot omit parameters at runtime, the parameters used must be determined at compile time. I don't see a way around repeating the default values:
val id = if (jsonObject.has(JSON.ID)) jsonObject.getInt(JSON.ID) else 0
val weight = if (jsonObject.has(JSON.WEIGHT)) jsonObject.getInt(JSON.WEIGHT) else 0

ScaleCapture(id, weight)

